# scrape websites using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im getting attribute error while scraping

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page ='https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find('h1', attires ={'class': 'name'})

name = name_box.text.strip()
print name
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "word1.py", line 11, in
>
> ```
> name = name_box.text.strip()
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
>
> Viveks-MacBook-Pro:py vivek$

Comment: what is _attires_  a typo?

Answer (score 1):

when you do this

```
print(name_box)
```

you will get

```
 None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/devsurya/python/demo programs/b4s.py", line 13, in <module>
    name = name_box.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

and when you do this -

```
print(soup)    ## it says following message with weird html and css
```

> We've detected unusual activity from your computer network

and `soup.find('h1', attires ={'class': 'name'})` should be `soup.find('h1', {'class': 'companyName__99a4824b'})`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the company name I would go with requests and a couple of headers are required (you will need to test to see if this performs consistently over time). I use a css attribute = value selector to get the appropriate element and use starts with operator ^ in case the value is dynamic i.e. I assume a constant start string of `companyName`. This makes it more versatile for other requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

quote_page ='https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'
page = requests.get(quote_page, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0', 'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9'})
soup = bs(page.content,'lxml')
name_box = soup.select_one('[class^=companyName]')
name = name_box.text.strip()
print(name)
```